# Change element.style with JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

First, there are many duplicates for this question but those answers don't give deeper insights.

Q1. Why this results in 200,0 ?

Consider this snippet:

```js
var el = document.querySelector('#r');

console.log('First:: ' + el.offsetHeight);

el.style = {
  height: el.offsetHeight + 500 + 'px'
}

console.log('Second:: ' + el.offsetHeight);
```

```html
<div id="r" style="height:200px;width:800px;overflow:auto;border:1px    solid;margin:20px;box-sizing:border-box"></div>
```

I suspect `el.style` to be read-only , so I expect setting an object should silently fail and therefore I expect the output to be

`First:: 200,Second:: 200`

but it is:

`First:: 200,Second:: 0`

Why ?

Q2. Why setting el.style using Object.assign works ?

```
Object.assign(el.style,{
   height : el.offsetHeight + 500 
})
```

Can someone please explain me with some deeper insights?

Comment: `el.style` is **not** read-only. You use it to get or **set** inline styles on an element. Accessing the `.style` property returns an object. That object has all the CSS properties. i.e. `el.style.height = '500px'`

Comment: @ScottMarcus Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style#Setting_style  (4th) says it is read-only, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yea , I accept setting property using `el.style.[property]` should work but it fails when assigning an object to `el.style`

Comment: Please check this link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-class-with-javascript

Answer (score 6):

**For your first question:**

MDN says that although the `style` object is read-only, FF, Chrome and Opera do allow assignments to it (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style). Now, the `offsetHeight` property is read-only (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight), so it appears that attempting to set  the `style` is causing that property to be reset to zero since `offsetHeight` is calculated value, not one that is set explicitly, and your browser is actually allowing the setting of the style property (albeit incorrectly).

**For your second question:**

The reason why `Object.assign` works is written right into the documentation for Object.assign. **It doesn't replace the object, it replaces the enumerable own properties of the object.** From:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

> "Properties in the target object will be overwritten by properties in
>   the sources if they have the same key.  Later sources' properties will
>   similarly overwrite earlier ones.
>
> The Object.assign() method only copies enumerable and own properties
>   from a source object to a target object."

So, in your first attempt:

```
el.style = {
  height: el.offsetHeight + 500 + 'px'
}
```

You are attempting to replace the entire object, which fails, but Object.assign just copies properties, which succeeds.

Comment: Thanks , I get it . But Q1 seems to be a nightmare .. why doest it results in 0

Answer (score 3):

Based on Chrome https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/d1a7b0cbd0a511459f0f6202dfe61e27aa47df46.,

When we set any property it forwards it to `el.style.cssText` (see the spec https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#the-cssstylerule-interface)

It says **[PutForwards=cssText]**

so when assigning a string.,

```
el.style = 'some valid css string'; 
// it takes the string and assigns to cssText 
el.style.cssText = 'some valid css string';

// So when assigning an object
el.style = {...}; 
// it takes the object and converts to string toString()
el.style.cssText = '[object Object]';
// Since it is not valid , it unsets everything
```

Answer (score 3):

I looked this up because I had a series of style properties that I wanted to change and wondered if I could do it using an object so it would look cleaner.
If anybody wonders and will stumble upon this subject, here's what I've come up with:

```js
  var setStyle = { 
    zIndex: 10000,
    position: "absolute",
    top: somey,
    left: somex,
    opacity: 1,
    height: someh + "px",
    width: somew + "px"
  }

  for(let prop of Object.keys(setStyle)){
    elem.style[prop.toString()] = setStyle[prop.toString()];
  }
```

Take care

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with this statement:

```
el.style = {
  height: el.offsetHeight + 500 + 'px'
};
```

Not only does this not work (as in, the element’s CSS `height` is *not* set to `700px`), but it also **removes** all inline styles that were previously set on the element (the `style` attribute):

[image]

And since your `<div>` is completely empty, its height will be zero. This is why `el.offsetHeight` returns `0` at the end.