# What is the difference between element.style="height: 90px;" and element.style.height="90px";?

Tags: javascript, css

Are there any differences between these 2 lines?

```
document.querySelector("div").style="height: 90px;"
document.querySelector("div").style.height="90px";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One difference is that when you assign to the `.style` property, you will overwrite whatever *used* to be assigned to the `.style` property, if anything:

```js
// this next assignment will be immediately overwritten!
document.querySelector("div").style = 'background-color: yellow';
document.querySelector("div").style = "height: 90px;"
```

```css
div {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  x
</div>
```

```js
// Not overwritten anymore!
document.querySelector("div").style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
document.querySelector("div").style.height = "90px";
```

```css
div {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  x
</div>
```

Another problem is that the `style` object is *supposed* to be read-only, although popular web browsers [allow it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40426862/change-element-style-with-javascript-object). See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style):

> Styles should not be set by assigning a string directly to the `style` property (as in `elt.style = "color: blue;"`), since it is considered read-only, as the style attribute returns a `CSSStyleDeclaration` object which is also read-only. Instead, styles can be set by assigning values to the properties of `style`. For adding specific styles to an element without altering other style values, it is preferred to use the individual properties of `style` (as in `elt.style.color = '...'`) as using `elt.style.cssText = '...'` or `elt.setAttribute('style', '...')` sets the complete inline style for the element by overriding the existing inline styles. Note that the property names are in camel-case and not kebab-case while setting the style using `elt.style.<property>` (i.e., `elt.style.fontSize`, not `elt.style.font-size`).

Assigning to it isn't a good idea. For better compatibility, assign to the `.style.cssText` (or only assign to a particular property, like `.height`):

```js
document.querySelector("div").style.cssText = "height: 90px;"
```

```css
div {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  x
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector("div").style="height: 90px;"` will override the entire `style` attribute of the selected div element, erasing any other properties that may have been set via the style attribute.

`document.querySelector("div").style.height="90px";` will only update the `height` property.